# How to select a list of files which matches multiple Regular Expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, expression, enumerable

I have the code working for a single reg. exp check, but now I need to check for another reg. expression.

Following is the current code,

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*(t|T)est\s+(c|C)ommon\s*");

var filelist = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*" + fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                               from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                               .Select(f => regex.Match(f))
                               .Where(m => m.Success)
                               select new
                               {
                                   File = file,
                                   Line = line
                               };
```

This gives me a list of file paths of files which contains 'Test Common'.
Now along with this check I need to check for 'Read Me'.

Basically I need to check if the file contains 'Test Common' and 'Read Me'.

**Updated**

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s*\b(type\s*:\s*test\s+common\b\s*\bowner\s*:\s*read\s+me\s*\b)\b\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    
    var filelist = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*" + fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                   from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                                   .Select(f => regex.Match(f))
                                   .Where(m => m.Success)
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       File = file,
                                       Line = line
                                   };
```

But this doesn't give any result.

-----Testing File-----

```
---
type: Test common
owner: Read ME
---

#All Tests

This will call all the Tests
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex pattern, which uses an alternation:

```
^.*\b(test common\b.*\bread me\b|\bread me\b.*\btest common)\b.*$

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*\b(test common\b.*\bread me\b|\bread me\b.*\btest common)\b.*$",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Another option would be to use two positive lookaheads which assert that each phrase appears:

```
^(?=.*\btest common\b(?=.*\b read me\b).*$
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, I tried to use the concept you said, '\b' I got it working in [regexr](https://regexr.com/57go1) however when I used the same expression in VS it doesn't give any result.

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s*\b(type\s*:\s*test\s+common\b\s*\bowner\s*:\s*read\s+me\s*\b)\b\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: The pattern you are using does not really match what is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single reg exp didn't work for this code because the reg expressions were in two separate lines not in the same line and that process made it more complex.
The easiest solution was to first filter from 1st reg exp , then filtering that result from second reg. exp. So Finlay I'm left with files where both reg. expressions match.

```
Regex regex_type = new Regex(@"\s*type\s*:\s*test\s+common\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Regex regex_owner = new Regex(@"\s*owner\s*:\s*read\s+me\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                

                //Filter from Type
                var filelist = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*" + fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                               from lines in File.ReadLines(file)
                               .Select(lines => regex_type.Match(lines))
                               .Where(m => m.Success)
                               select file;

                //Then filter that from owner
                filelist = from file in filelist
                           from lines in File.ReadLines(file)
                           .Select(lines => regex_owner.Match(lines))
                           .Where(m => m.Success)
                           select file;
```